# Exhausting floating point precision in a (seemingly) infinite loop

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I've got the following Python script:

```
x = 300000000.0
while (x < x + x):
    x = x + x
    print "exec: " + str(x)
print "terminated" + str(x)
```

This seemingly infinite loop, terminates pretty quickly if x is a floating point number. But if i change x to 300000000 instead, it gets into an infinite loop (runs longer than a minute in my test).

I think this is to do with the fact that it's exhausting the precision of a floating point number that can be represented in memory. Can someone provide a more detailed explanation why this is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- When you initialize `x` to `300000000`, integer math is used throughout the program.
- When you initialize `x` to `300000000.0`, floating-point math is used instead.

In Python, integers can grow arbitrarily large. (More accurately, they're limited by the available memory.) This means that the integer version of your program takes a very long time to terminate.

The largest `float` is about `1.8e308`. It takes about 1000 iterations of the floating-point version of the loop to exceed that value, at which point `x` gets set to positive infinity, and the program terminates.

Comment: voted as correct answer since this actually why it explains it doesn't terminate for the integer case, where other answers just explained the obvious that it terminates when x = inf if x is a float

Answer (score 6):

This is because a floating-point overflow occurs. In that case, [as per IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Exception_handling), `x` will adopt the value positive infinity, which is by definition not less than anything else:

```
>>> x = float("inf")
>>> x
inf
>>> x + x
inf
>>> x < x + x
False
```

Answer (score 4):

`x` doubles after each step. A finite number `x` is never equal to `2 * x`. But once you exceed the maximum exponent of your floating point type, the doubling turns `x` to `+infinity`. And `+infinity = 2*+infinity`. So the loop terminates at that point.