# Infinite while loop when checking floats for equality

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, floating-accuracy

**I'm having an infinite loop when I run this code:**

```
intensity = 0.50
while intensity != 0.65:
    print(intensity)
    intensity = intensity + 0.05
```

intensity values should be like  0.50 -> 0.55 -> 0.60 -> 0.65 then it should gets out of the loop.
Why the program is doing an infinite loop instead?

Comment: For one thing, you get floating-point errors, so at the second iteration `intensity` is `0.6000000000000001` and the loop never closes. Rounding would fix this. However, I don't know why it isn't printing the value, so I have upvoted your question.

Answer (score 9):

Because of floating point imprecision, you may not end up with *exactly* `0.65`.

To solve this, use `<` rather than `!=` <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
intensity = 0.50
while intensity < 0.65:
    print(intensity)
    intensity = intensity + 0.05
```

The output of that (showing what I mean by imprecision as well) is:

```
0.5
0.55
0.6000000000000001
```

If you kept going, you'd see:

```
0.6500000000000001
0.7000000000000002
0.7500000000000002
0.8000000000000003
```

which is why it's never equal to `0.65`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You may be wondering what the situation would be if the next value was `0.6499...9` rather than `0.650..1`, and you would probably be right to be concerned.

While using `<` will fix the latter case, you'll almost certainly get one iteration too many for the former case.

You can fix that by a number of possible different strategies, some of which are:

- round the number to the correct number of decimals before comparing, such as `round(intensity, 2)`.
- compare it with a "close enough" check, such as the absolute difference being less that `10-4` (for example) - something like `if abs(intensity - 0.65) < 0.0001`.
- use integral values exclusively and scale the value as needed (e.g., initialising `intensity` to `50`, adding `5`, comparing to `65`, and printing `round(intensity / 100, 2)`.

The Python documentation has [an interesting article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) that you can read to further understand these limitations.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the way Python (and some other languages like C) handle floating-point provisions. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414992/exhausting-floating-point-precision-in-a-seemingly-infinite-loop) or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/). In general, you should avoid floating point loop counters.

If you still wanted to use one, you can round it off:

```
intensity = 0.50
while round(intensity,2) != 0.65:
    print(round(intensity,2))
    intensity = intensity + 0.05
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while True:
    if intensity>0.65:
        break
    print(intensity)
    intensity+=0.05
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at your output:

```
0.5
0.55
0.6000000000000001
0.6500000000000001
0.7000000000000002
```

0.05 cannot be exactly represented with a terminating binary float number.

See [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014)

If you want to check whether the value is *close*, then simply set your desired tolerance:

```
while abs(intensity - 0.65) < my_tolerance:
```

Better yet, use the built-in function, setting either relative or absolute tolerance:

```
isclose(intensity, 0.65, rel_tol=1e-9, abs_tol=0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Quickly editing your code to observe how intensity increases:

```
from time import sleep

intensity = 0.50
while intensity != 0.65:
    print("The intensity is:", intensity)
    intensity = intensity + 0.05
    sleep(5)
```

This gets stuck in an infinite loops since, the value of  `intensity` never reaches `0.65`
The O/P is as follows:

```
The intensity is: 0.5
The intensity is: 0.55
The intensity is: 0.6000000000000001
The intensity is: 0.6500000000000001
The intensity is: 0.7000000000000002
The intensity is: 0.7500000000000002
The intensity is: 0.8000000000000003
The intensity is: 0.8500000000000003
The intensity is: 0.9000000000000004
The intensity is: 0.9500000000000004
The intensity is: 1.0000000000000004
...
...
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 3):

i tried running the following code and the output was

```
intensity = 0.50
>>> n = 1
>>> while intensity!=0.65 and n<7:
...     print(intensity)
...     intensity = intensity + .05
...     n = n+1
```

output

```
0.5
0.55
0.6000000000000001
0.6500000000000001
0.7000000000000002
0.7500000000000002
```

the loop turns infinite because the 4th output is not exactly .65 it is .65000000001.

try this one and it will work

```
while float(str(intensity)[:4])!=0.65 :
...     print(intensity)
...     intensity = intensity + .05
```

...

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this behaviour by using the **python** `built-in` `round` function. The `round` function will round a number to a given precision in decimal digits.

So you can try something like this

```
>>> intensity = 0.50
>>> 
>>> while intensity != 0.65:
...     print(intensity)
...     intensity = round(intensity + 0.05, 2)
0.5
0.55
0.6
```